# Pinta fill-transparent for everything lighter than black?

Tags: transparency, fill, pinta

I have an image which I wanted to set the background as transparent for, which was pretty straightforward in Pinta due to a great tutorial. But I was left with a faint whiteish grayish outline when I pasted the image over a dark background.

The advice I found online for this was to increase the "tolerance" of the bucket fill param, but this didn't work for me. Adjusting the tolerance bit-by-bit, I found tolerance of 35 still didn't get rid of the border, and tolerance 36 applied fill-transparent to parts of my actual image.

So now I'm zoomed in to 1200% and filling-transparent pixel by pixel around my image. All these pixels are shades of gray, and I just leave alone everything that's black (which delineates the outline of my image). But there's got to be a better way to "fill everything in this region lighter than black" right?

Comment: Tutorial can look great but can still be wrong. Anything that doesn't produce partial opacity on the edge pixels can only be sneered at. I don't know Pinta so cannot explain the "right" method. Elsewhere it is called "color to alpha".

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [The Free & Open Source Image Editor GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). GIMP is a cross-platform image editor available for GNU/Linux, OS X, Windows and more operating systems.

You can do `Color -> Color to Alpha`. See [this Stack Exchange about Color to Alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28058/gimp-color-to-alpha-is-not-selectable) for an example of getting started.

Alternatively, you can `Select -> Select by Color`

Answer (score 0):

GIMP is awesome, but it is also quite the heavyweight. I looked around for an open source bitmap editor with more features than Pinta but fewer than GIMP and came across [Krita](https://krita.org) (KDE project).

It wasn't quite what I was hoping for, but it might be a good balance for others. It also has a [color-to-alpha feature](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/filters/colors.html).