# Make transparent rain layer to use as overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, overlay

I have followed this tutorial to make a rain
[le link](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/rain/)
and it works ok with a picture in it, using that blend mode Screen, but I want to make that rain layer to not have black background, and have the rain, so I can use it as an overlay in programming. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You could change all of the black to transparency as is answered [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/replace-black-background-with-a-transparent-background)

Or a possible alternative since you are programming (depending on what you are programming of course) could be to program the behavior that the screen blend mode enforces;

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen);

> With Screen blend mode the values of the pixels in the two layers are inverted, multiplied, and then inverted again. This yields the opposite effect to multiply. The result is a brighter picture.
>
> f(a,b) = 1 - (1 - a)(1 - b), where a is the base layer value and b is the top layer value.
>
> This mode is symmetric: exchanging two layers does not change the result. If one layer contains a homogeneous gray, Screen blend mode is equivalent to using this gray value as opacity when doing “normal mode” blend with white top layer.

Best of luck!