# How to reduce white in an image using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, white

I want to reduce the white in this image. So that the structure is somehow faded into the blue background. How can I do that in Photoshop? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate, @Vahid please refer to this answer  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/replace-black-background-with-a-transparent-background/4057#4057

Comment: Thanks but didn't work for me :(

Comment: Try this one. select adjustment layer and in properties tab choose color as white. try changing the cyan & magenta. all the white coloured area in the image will turn into blue shades.

Comment: Thanks can you please explain it a bit more? How to select the adjustment layer? What to choose in the adjustment options?

Comment: How is this file structured? Is the background on a separate layer? Do you mean for the building to fade at the left- and right-ends? Please explain more what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could do it a simple way by creating a layer under the image that is the same dark blue and then turn down the opacity of the top layer until you're happy with the amount that its blended in.