# How do I remove a green screen background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal

How can I green screen in Photoshop? I am making a picture were I need to green screen, and it would be very helpful if someone could help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alpha Transparency Remove Background Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/alpha-transparency-remove-background-photoshop). Check out that question, it should answer this one. There's also [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/completely-remove-background-from-image) as well.

Comment: [This technique](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25873/how-do-i-make-a-color-background-transparent/25874#25874) might also work and doesn't require any tracing or erasing. As green is kind of a mid-tone, you'd just have to darken the greens in hue/saturation first.

Comment: Magic Wand tool with proper tolerance value might help you to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

- Select > Color Range
- Click a part of the image which is green
- Adjust the "Fuzziness" slider

Comment: It turns black and white.

Comment: The **selection preview** is black and white, yes. But once you click OK you have a selection which can be made into a mask.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 1 image and the subject is not extremely complicated (outline is relatively simple) than I would make a path around the subject and then make a selection out of that. Then hit Select -> Refine Edge and play with the settings there until you get a good separation from the background.

If you want to go full auto, check out this great tutorial: http://www.photoshop.com/tutorials/4082

Comment: I knew that. But I need something more detailed.

Comment: More detailed on the technique I gave or do you need a more refined image result?

Comment: I've update my answer with a new tutorial for complete automation (no paths involved)

Comment: @OskarSkaane The technique CatalinM gave was as descriptive as your question was. If you are looking for a better answer it might help to provide more detailed information or allowing those helping to understand what it is you've done in trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic wand tool to remove it. Search on youtube "removing backgrounds using the magic wand tool" and you will see tons of them showing you how it's done. It's not that difficult. I also know that for after effects you can remove it using the key light plugin and it is very easy to do so as well I learned that here: https://www.udemy.com/learntvads. But back to your question on photoshop it can be done with the magic wand.