# Photoshop - Best way to remove a greenscreen background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-quality, image-editing, image-trace

I have about 16 photos of teammates standing in front of a green screen. I have to remove all the green obviously, usually, I do this with the magic wand tool but what is the best/cleanest way to do it?

Any good tutorials out there?

Comment: See [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20676/63979) by Scott.

Comment: Plenty of tutorials, many questions in GD.SE with great answers.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqUBcMv50ZM

This seems to be the best one after 30min of searching

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.