# Removing the white background from images with shadows

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

Is there an easy way to remove the white background from these images? Some of them have shadows so Wand Tool is not that precise.

[image: example image with cutout background]

<sup>Google Drive link to images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2zBo690ggSdMWZYUzdqREVFNmM</sup>

Comment: Check this questions, lots of techniques there: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/how-to-completely-remove-the-background-from-an-image?rq=1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of the **magic wand tool and the pen tool** if using Photoshop.

I would first adjust the image using levels adjustment. I would increase the white point and make the midpoints overall darker

[image: levels adjustment]

Now I would use the magic wand tool to get a basic selection.

[image: selecting the suitcase.]

I had to use the quick selection tool to deselect some areas (Mostly around the handles). You may want to mess with the refine mask tool.

I made that selection into a layer mask for the suitcase.

I would then go in closer with the pen tool to make a selection for the bottom of the suitcases.

Comment: Just a personal preference for quality but magic wand tool is very sloppy. Sorry, I have shivers down the spine whenever I see magic wand tool as a suggestion for cutout haha! Using a brush on a layer mask is always 100% perfect and you can add some fake anti-aliasing effect too to merge the white with the picture better.

Comment: @go-me I could have suggested multiple of different ways. I was answering more of the "easiest" way rather than the "best" way of making a selection.

Comment: Yes it works too, and lot of people like to use the wand for the first selection and then adjust it in the layer mask, as I think you suggested too.