# Extracting an image from a white background in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal, white

I have a set of images that background color and the object color is white. So its hard to extract(selecting) the object. Is there any way to make this easier?

Example of an image
[image]

Comment: Hello tha07, welcome to GDSE. Please have a look at [tag:background-removal]. We have load of questions about this subject there, and some of those should help you. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove the background from an image?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/how-to-completely-remove-the-background-from-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem in the past with white objects on white backgrounds. I add an adjustment layer in photoshop and crank up the levels really high so I can see the edges, then I create a path around the object. The path can then be made into a clipping path, or turned into a selection for a mask. Then the adjustment layer can be removed or turned off with no damage to your original file.