# I want to remove all the white

Tags: images, white-space

Hi I wanted to remove the white background in the image below how would i use that and what applications/websites can I use to remove the white and  i'm using a mac just incase you have an app that's not compatible with mac. All help appreciated. 😁
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove the background from an image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/how-to-completely-remove-the-background-from-an-image)

Comment: Please have a look at the questions and answers in our [tag:background-removal] category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here you go.

Quick use of the Magic Wand Tool in Photoshop to select all the white pixels.